# Docker-compose cant reach second command

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I have my docker-compose.yaml file like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
      sh -c "python simple_script.py"
```

and the problem is that when i run `docker-compose up` it never reaches the second command ( `sh -c "python simple_script.py"` ) .

I think this is because the first command `sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"` never exits.

Is there a way to run two commands like this?

Comment: Run the non-blocking code first, or use two containers, or if both are daemons use a process manager like supervisord. Or run the 2nd command with `docker exec`...

Comment: A container only runs one command, but you can have multiple containers running on the same image.  Since in fact the Django server won't exit, if you want to run a second command while that's running you'll need an approach like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you try this one:

```
sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 & python simple_script.py"
```

In linux you can use `&` to run commands in background.
You can use `fg` to get back to it.

Comment: This may not be what you're after: when `simple_script.py` completes, the container will exit, and if the Django server fails for some reason, Docker simply won't notice it.  It's typically better to run multiple containers with one process per container.

Comment: The best practice is to run them in multiple containers, but question was something else. @DavidMaze

Answer (score -2):

You can write two commands in one line. like this -

```
sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 && python simple_script.py"
```

Comment: This would still block.

Comment: When I run `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 && python3 simple_script.py` the server begins to run, but the simple_script.py does not run until I quit the server.